# C# WebForm, how to access HyperLink Text value inside DATALIST?

Tags: c#, datalist

Is it possible to access the Text of ProductName inside this Hyperlink (DATALIST) ?

Thank you!!

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" CellPadding="0" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ShowFooter="False" ShowHeader="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" Text='<%# Eval("productName") %>' runat="server" Font-Size="Large"></asp:HyperLink>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: If you mean if you can access the text value using script after it is rendered then yes, you can.

Comment: Please provide some more context. There is no datalist in your code sample. And you tagged this as gridview. That's not the same as datalist.

Comment: Corrected! Thanks

Comment: Now what are you trying to do exactly? What to you mean by 'access the text value'? I suspect you need to set the NavigateUrl property dynamically ... just a guess ...

Comment: I wanted to store the text value of HyperLink1 inside a string, so something like string s1 = ProductName of selected datalist index